# How to clear form after submitting

Tags: angular

Hi i'm using angular7 and my problem is when i want to send my form he send it and when i reset it i have a validation of validators required how to clear my form after submitting without verification of required input

this is my code ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { FuseTranslationLoaderService } from '@fuse/services/translation-loader.service';
import { AuthService } from 'app/services/auth.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from 'app/models/user.model';
import { locale as english } from 'app/pages/dnsaas-access-request/i18n/en'
import { locale as french } from 'app/pages/dnsaas-access-request/i18n/fr'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dnsaas-access-request',
  templateUrl: './dnsaas-access-request.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dnsaas-access-request.component.scss']
})
export class DnsaasAccessRequestComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;
  domains: FormArray;
  user: User;
  domainPattern = /^(?!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.){0,5}[a-zA-Z0-9-][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,64}?$/;
  groupPattern = /^[a-zA-Z_]+$/;
  // Private
  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param {FormBuilder} _formBuilder
   */
  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _fuseTranslationLoaderService: FuseTranslationLoaderService,
    private _authService: AuthService,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService
  ) {
    // Set the private defaults
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
    this._fuseTranslationLoaderService.loadTranslations(english, french);
  }
  ngAfterContentChecked() {

    this.cdref.detectChanges();

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Reactive Form
    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstname: [''],
      lastname: [''],
      email: [''],
      group: ['', Validators.required],
      requested_domains: this._formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()]),
      comment: ['',],
    });


    this._authService.getAuthStatusListener()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        if (user) {
          this.form.patchValue({
            firstname: user.first_name,
            lastname: user.last_name,
            email: user.user_email
          })
        }

      });
  }

  /**
   * On destroy
   */
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
    this._unsubscribeAll.next();
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
  }
  get primaryEmail() {
    return this.form.get('email');
  }

  get requested_domains() {
    return this.form.get('requested_domains');
  }

  get group() {
    return this.form.get('group')
  }

  initItemRows(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      domain_name: [''],
      right: ['']
    });

  }

  Send() {
    const request = this.form.value;
    this.spinner.show();
    this._authService.formulaire(request).subscribe(res => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.toastr.success("Your form has been successfully sent");
      if(this.form.valid){
        this.form.get('requested_domains').;
        this.form.get('group').reset();
        this.form.get('comment').reset();
      }

    },
      error => {
        this.toastr.error("Your form has not been sent");
        setTimeout(() => {
          /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
          this.spinner.hide();
        }, 1000);
      }
    );
  }



  addDomains() {
    this.domains = this.form.get('requested_domains') as FormArray;
    this.domains.push(this.initItemRows());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    this.domains.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

And this is my code HTML :

```
<div id="forms" class="page-layout simple fullwidth" fxLayout="column">

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <div class="header accent p-24 h-160" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
      <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
        <mat-icon class="secondary-text s-18">home</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="secondary-text s-16">chevron_right</mat-icon>
        <span class="secondary-text">{{'contDNS-Acces-Requestact.DNSaaS Access Request' | translate}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="h1 mt-16">{{'DNS-Acces-Request.DNSaaS Access Request' | translate}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / HEADER -->
  <div class="content p-24">
    <p class="pt-16 pb-32">
      {{'DNS-Acces-Request.Please fill out the form below to make your request and we will process your request as soon as possible.' | translate}}
    </p>
    <div class="mb-24" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayout.gt-md="row">
      <form class="mat-card mat-elevation-z4 p-24 mr-24" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxFlex="1 0 auto"
        name="form" [formGroup]="form">

        <div class="" style="text-align: center">
          <img class="logo-ca" src="assets/images/logos/snap.png">
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">

          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pr-4">
            <mat-label>{{'DNS-Acces-Request.First name' | translate}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="firstname" readonly>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">account_circle</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>

          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="50" class="pl-4">
            <mat-label>{{'DNS-Acces-Request.Last name' | translate}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="lastname" readonly>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">account_circle</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>

        </div>

        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pl-4">
            <mat-label>{{'DNS-Acces-Request.Email' | translate}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="email" readonly>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">mail</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pl-4">
            <mat-label>{{'DNS-Acces-Request.AD Group' | translate}}</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="group" [pattern]="groupPattern">
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">group</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="group.errors?.required">{{'DNS-Acces-Request.AD Group is required!' | translate}}
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="group.errors?.pattern">{{'DNS-Acces-Request.AD Group is not Valid!' | translate}}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div formArrayName="requested_domains"
          *ngFor="let domain of form.controls.requested_domains.controls; let i = index" fxLayout="row wrap"
          fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
          <div [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="40" class="pl-4">
              <mat-label>{{'DNS-Acces-Request.Domain' | translate}}</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="domain_name" required [pattern]="domainPattern">
              <mat-error *ngIf="requested_domains.errors?.required">
                {{'DNS-Acces-Request.Invalid domains!' | translate}}</mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="requested_domains.errors?.pattern">
                {{'DNS-Acces-Request.Invalid domains!' | translate}}</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-radio-group formControlName="right" aria-label="Select an option" appearance="outline" fxFlex="40"
              class="pl-4" required>
              <mat-radio-button style="font-size : 11px; margin-left: 10px" value="R">
                {{'DNS-Acces-Request.READ' | translate}}</mat-radio-button>
              <mat-radio-button style="font-size : 11px; margin-left: 10px" value="RW">
                {{'DNS-Acces-Request.READ/WRITE' | translate}}</mat-radio-button>
            </mat-radio-group>
          </div>
          <mat-icon title="Ajouter" fxFlex="10" mat-icon-button color="basic" (click)="addDomains()"
            style="color:#3c5d80; cursor: pointer">add_circle</mat-icon>
          <mat-icon *ngIf="form.controls.requested_domains.controls.length > 1" title="Supprimer" fxFlex="10"
            mat-icon-button color="basic" (click)="deleteRow(i)" style="color:#dd2d2d; cursor: pointer">
            delete_forever</mat-icon>

        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pl-4">
            <mat-label>Message</mat-label>
            <textarea matInput formControlName="comment"></textarea>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">message</mat-icon>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div fxLayoutAlign="end center">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="Send()">{{'DNS-Acces-Request.Send'
                    | translate }}</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)" size="medium" color="#fff" type="ball-clip-rotate"></ngx-spinner>
</div>
```

This my form in image here after submitting form :

[image]
This is my code please help to resolve this probleme

Comment: Have you tried: `form.resetForm()`?

Comment: yes when i tried this after submitting i have the verification required field in my input

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: it is not possible unfortunately

Comment: Where did you reset the form values?

Comment: in the function send()

Comment: Have you tried this `myForm.form.markAsPristine()`?

Comment: thank you for your answer I tested it keeps the values ​​sent

Comment: return a form group instance and set it to ``this.form``

Comment: @CruelEngine how to do it ?? thanks

Comment: @AbdelhaqBENDIDANE please check my answer

Comment: @CruelEngine i checked your answer read my comment

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.form.controls['input'].reset();// one by one OR this.form.reset();
formDirective.resetForm();
```

formDirective is instance of FormGroupDirective

Comment: how to do formDirective.resetForm() ??

Comment: i tried this thats worked but he reset all form , i want just reset 3 input ??

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective  check here is API for this, and try 
removeControl(dir: FormControlName): void method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearValidators()` to clear the validators

```
this.form.get('group').reset();
this.form.get('comment').reset();

this.form.clearValidators(); // and then call `clearValidators` method
```

Here is [`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9zvldr)

Comment: @AbdelhaqBENDIDANE you can refer the Stackblitz example it works fine there

Comment: i tried it with your stackblitz but  the problem still exists try to send after copmplete the field

Comment: @AbdelhaqBENDIDANE unable to reproduce!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to reset your form on submit but with all your validators intact , you return a `new formGroup` and assign it to your `form variable` on successful submit.

You can do it in the below way :

create a function that returns a `formGroup` :

```
getMyForm(){
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      firstname: [''],
      lastname: [''],
      email: [''],
      group: ['', Validators.required],
      requested_domains: this._formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()]),
      comment: ['',],
    });
}
```

All you need to do is assign `this.form=this.getMyForm()` and you'll have a new instance with all your validators intact .

```
 Send() {
    const request = this.form.value;
    this.spinner.show();
    this._authService.formulaire(request).subscribe(res => {
      this.spinner.hide();
      this.toastr.success("Your form has been successfully sent");
      if(this.form.valid){
        this.form = this.getMyForm()
      }

    },
      error => {
        this.toastr.error("Your form has not been sent");
        setTimeout(() => {
          /** spinner ends after 5 seconds */
          this.spinner.hide();
        }, 1000);
      }
    );
  }
```

You can also refer to the below stackblitz example :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rubcdg

Comment: when i use this i have the same problem and he reset all my form

Comment: @AbdelhaqBENDIDANE your question clearly states you want to reset your form without your values being validated and nothing about selective reset of form controls in form group